# How to load js in view AFTER serving application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm having a problem when pushing to heroku in my rails app.

Lots of functions become `undefined`, because `<%= javascript_include_tags %>` are being included before `application.js`, so libraries are not loaded.

I've tried the "defer" in my script tags, but didn't work.

It's happening ONLY in production, not in my dev environment.

**How can I specify Rails to load JS in my view the latest?**

Any advice would be great. Thanks

**CASE:**

**My application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.lockfixed
//= require jquery.base64
//= require jquery.browser.mobile
//= require masonry.pkgd.min
//= require_directory ./utils
//= require_directory ./helpers
//= require tabs
//= require pining
//= require list
//= require handlebars
//= require jquery.cookiesdirective
//= require albums
//= require landing
//= require bxslider
//= require landing/waypoints
//= require landing/animate-waypoints
//= require handlebars-truncate-helper
//= require spots
```

**My view**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "call_pining_function" %>
```

**Call_pining_function partial**

```
drawStaticPin();
```

**Error in Heroku**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: drawStaticPin is not defined
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you give a link to actual case, to see it more clearly what is happening?

Comment: @sanfor Please see attached case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I still aren't completely sure about this case. I assume that

```
//= require pining
```

is the file that contains the drawStaticPin, right?
There are few options that I can see here:

First, Put your "call_pining_function" into the requires of application.js

Second, If the call_pining_function is defined after jQuery (DOM) is ready, possibly you could tie the function call to that event

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    drawStaticPin();
};
```

Third, Ugly but does the job assuming that the code will eventually be loaded

```
while (typeof drawStaticPin === "undefined");
drawStaticPin();
```

Comment: Hi there, the first solution is "clean", but I don't want to load call_pining_function in every view... The second solution is quite dirty, don't want to rely on Jquery for this!